# Cant access Alfresco file with CMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I have a Drupal project which makes API calls to Alfresco via CMIS

I have used my own custom module which uses the PHP version of Apache chemistry to make CMIS calls.

Previously the site worked perfectly (ie I did not have the problem described bellow).

However now when I try to download a file via the Drupal site I get an error generated by Alfresco.

Drupal is still able to log into alfresco, browse the folder tree and view file information. The only problem is that it cant obtain files.

This started after the server which Alfresco was on was rebooted.

Interestingly I am still able to download files using Alfrescos web interface and a different CMIS client (CMIS workbench).

This is the error (yes it is a long one).

---

```
CmisObjectNotFoundException: <html><head><title>Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS - objectNotFound error</title><style><!--H1 {font-size:24px;line-height:normal;font-weight:bold;background-color:#f0f0f0;color:#003366;border-bottom:1px solid #3c78b5;padding:2px;} BODY {font-family:Verdana,arial,sans-serif;color:black;font-size:14px;} HR {color:#3c78b5;height:1px;}--></style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404
- <!--exception-->objectNotFound<!--/exception--></h1><p><!--message-->Object not found: download_file<!--/message--></p><hr noshade='noshade'/><!--stacktrace--><pre> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Object not found: download_file at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISNodeInfoImpl.checkIfUseful(CMISNodeInfoImpl.java:973) at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getOrCreateNodeInfo(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:225) at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getObject(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:1741) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1529.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:79) at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457) at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.java:72) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.java:101) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.java:83) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy286.getObject(Unknown Source) at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.support.wrapper.ConformanceCmisServiceWrapper.getObject(ConformanceCmisServiceWrapper.java:914) at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.atompub.ObjectService$GetObject.serve(ObjectService.java:378) at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.shared.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91) at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.atompub.CmisAtomPubServlet.dispatch(CmisAtomPubServlet.java:226) at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.server.impl.atompub.CmisAtomPubServlet.service(CmisAtomPubServlet.java:173) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISServletDispatcher.execute(CMISServletDispatcher.java:188) at org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISWebScript.execute(CMISWebScript.java:51) at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:437) at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:45) at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:619) at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:399) at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:280) at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.access$001(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:26) at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer$1.doWork(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:81) at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsWork(TenantUtil.java:119) at org.alfresco.repo.tenant.TenantUtil.runAsTenant(TenantUtil.java:88) at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiRepositoryContainer.executeScript(PublicApiRepositoryContainer.java:77) at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378) at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209) at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TenantWebScriptServlet.service(TenantWebScriptServlet.java:74) at org.alfresco.rest.api.PublicApiWebScriptServlet.service(PublicApiWebScriptServlet.java:53) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:68) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1460.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:125) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy270.doFilter(Unknown Source) at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2403) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) </pre><!--/stacktrace--><hr noshade='noshade'/></body></html> in CMISRepositoryWrapper->convertStatusCode() (line 168 of /var/www/html/demo_site/sites/all/modules/custom_cmis/libraries/cmis_repository_wrapper.php).
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same endpoint for both your php site and the other CMIS client ? Are you sure it is not a matter of authorization of certain user to a specific ressource ?

Comment: Yes
I copy/pasted the enpoint, username and password from the drupal module code to CMIS workbench

CMIS workbench works, Drupal does not

I also tested it using a simple PHP script that just uses the CMISservice constructor (with the same endpoint username and pass) and gestContentStream() function and that was able to access it

Comment: Then the problem should either be with the version of the library used in your project or in the implementation itself !

Comment: I have discovered that my code does successfully return the content stream
However

If put print($stream) at the end of the function it works (ether displays it in browser or offers it as a download file depending on the HTTP headder)
but 

If i put return $stream i get the CMIS error

Interestingly the error appears inside the red box which drupal generates when you use drupal_set_error()

I get the same result no matter what i try to return (ie return 'hello world' would also do the same thing.

Does this give any more clues as to what is going on?